# Xna 4 Model Rotation with inertia not working as expected with variable updates

Tags: c#, xna, frame-rate

I am trying to rotate a model with inertia damping with the keyboard.
The code works great with a fixed time step but it doesn't behave the same with a variable update frequency.

Update method:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);

    float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    const float rotationPerSecond = 0.25f;
    const float decayPerSecond = 0.5f;

    KeyboardState kb = Keyboard.GetState();

    if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    {
        m_velocity += rotationPerSecond * elapsed;
    }
    else if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    {
        m_velocity -= rotationPerSecond * elapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Math.Abs(m_velocity) < 0.01f)
        {
            m_velocity = 0;
        }
        else if (m_velocity > 0)
        {
            m_velocity -= decayPerSecond * elapsed;
        }
        else if (m_velocity < 0)
        {
            m_velocity += decayPerSecond * elapsed;
        }
    }

    m_rotationAngle += m_velocity;
}
```

Draw method:

```
Matrix rot = Matrix.CreateWorld(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.Forward, Vector3.Up) * 
                         Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(m_rotationAngle));
```

I am changing the time step with

```
IsFixedTimeStep = true;
graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = true;
```

and

```
IsFixedTimeStep = false;
graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false;
```

Rotation speed and damping is completely different with different update frequencies.
Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I've tested your code (but I apply rotation to a 2d sprite), works fine. Maybe the higher refresh rates make "more smoothly" effect instead of lower refresh rates "more laggy".

Comment: I' ve used System.Dignostics.StopWatch to measure the time of angle interval (m_rotationAngle = 180) and it shows same time for fixed time step/not fixed time step (4 seconds 897/914 ms).

Comment: Full Solution can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/znbqybc14wu8k3r/WindowsGame3.zip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds at m_rotationAngle calculation:

```
m_rotationAngle += m_velocity * elapsed;
```

And then increase your speed values:

```
const float rotationPerSecond = 250.0f;
const float decayPerSecond = 500.0f;
```

And it will work both for:

```
//IsFixedTimeStep = true/false;
//graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = true/false;
```